# Почему составная команда с ошибкой не генерирует ошибку?

Tags: bash, переменные

Есть bash-скрипт со следующей командой:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
sudo -u postgres bash -c cd /tmp ; psql -f /tmp/sql.txt
```

В нем есть ошибка: под пользователем **postgres** выполняется команда до символов **";"**, а бинарник **psql** вызывается уже не под пользователем **postgres**. И это дает ошибку:

```
psql: СБОЙ:  роль "root" не существует
```

Так и должно быть.

---

А теперь есть скрипт, в котором та же самая команда конструируется через переменную:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
psqlRun="sudo -u postgres bash -c cd /tmp ; "
$psqlRun psql -f /tmp/sql.txt
```

Запускаем это дело и... Ошибки нет! Вот только никаких действий, записанных в `/tmp/sql.txt` в БД PostgreSQL этот скрипт не выполнит. Но и не скажет об этом. Просто молча не сработает и все.

Вопрос: почему так? По-сути, создается команда, всеми символами совпадающая с командой из первого скрипта. Но почему этот скрипт не генерирует ошибку?

Comment: `sudo -u postgres "bash -c cd /tmp ; psql -f /tmp/sql.txt"` - передайте обе команды на выполнение от имени пользователя взяв их в кавычку. Так как есть разделитель команд, то интерпретатор считает ее следующей командой, не относящейся к предыдущей

Comment: Впрочем я вообще не понимаю смысла этой конструкции. Кажется тут достаточно просто `sudo -u postgres psql -f /tmp/sql.txt` без всяких дополнительных команд.

Comment: @AlexeyTen я так понимаю автор вопроса скрывает цели работы, думаю команды написаны для примера

Answer (score 1):

Потому что `;` внутри строки не является разделителем команд.

Простой пример:

```bsh
a='echo 1 ;'
$a echo 2
```

выведет `1 ; echo 2`, а не `1` и `2`.

Можно смотреть что там на самом деле исполняется.

```
$ cat a.sh
a="echo 1 ;"
$a echo 2

$ bash -x a.sh
+ a='echo 1 ;'
+ echo 1 ';' echo 2
1 ; echo 2
```

Как видите тут `;` заключена в кавычки, т.е. является просто строкой, а не разделителем команд.

Comment: Тогда другой вопрос: а как внутри строки написать разделитель команд?

Comment: @Xintrea лучше расскажите зачем так извращаться? Я сильно подозреваю что есть гораздо более простое решение.

Comment: Получается, не только ';' не является разделителем команд. Получается, что все, что идет за этим не-разделителем, тоже командой не является а является строкой?

Comment: Ну очевидно что пока команда не кончилась это всё аргументы первой команды. В моём примере это аргументы команды `echo`

Comment: Очень долго рассказывать. Вышеуказанная проблема возникла в скриптах автоматизации, предназначенных для Astra Linux 1.6 в режиме мандатного контроля целостности. Если перед командой **psql** не перейти в каталог /tmp, то она не выполнится, потому что для своей работы она пытается создать временный файл, а он не может создасться из-за мандатных меток, и единственно гарантированное место где он может без проблем запуститься - это каталог /tmp (с sed при inplace-редактировании файла та же проблема кстати, но она по-другому решается).

Comment: То есть, нужно одновременно: переключиться на пользователя postgre, находясь под ним перейти в каталог /tmp, и выполнить psql. В общем до мандатных меток работал просто psql, а с мандатными его уже просто так не запустишь. И поэтому приходится комбинировать его с дополнительными командами. А если конструировать, команду, то возникает топикстартовая проблема. А так как она НЕ генерирует ошибку, то НЕ сразу обнаруживается. И нужно железно понять почему это происходит, чтобы в будущем не наткнуться на похожее поведение в другом месте.

Comment: @"Alexey Ten" Но в топикстартовом скрипте непонятно, аргументом чего становится строка после ";" - аргументом команды **sudo** или команды **bash**?